# Does Sebastian have feelings for Ciel?

Tags: black-butler

The title is a bit misleading, because I am not talking about love.

I have watched the two seasons (and haven't read the manga).
In the second season, Sebastian hints that he "feels" degraded since he has to be a butler just to get Ciel's delicious soul. But since I've read the second season isn't canon. I doubted it.

I was wondering if this is actually true or if he has feelings towards Ciel. As in he is loyal towards Ciel and would never betray him. Some kind of friendship or something like that if you know what I mean.

Sebastian is never "pissed off" by orders from Ciel or anything and always smiles. Something I wouldn't expect from a devil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is intentionally vague, so this question is more asking for opinion

You can decide if you think they are friends or if you think he is proud to have cultivated a tasty contract

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that Sebastian has feelings for Ciel. My reasoning is because he decides to save Ciel, instead of letting him die. Also, I have noticed that Sebastian is never frustrated by Ciel, in any of the chapters. He is also taking better care of Ciel than he is required. So I guess he has some sort of feelings for Ciel.

Answer (score 0):

Do I think Sebastian has feelings for Ciel? In a way, yes, because if you watch seasons 1, 2, the *Book of Murders*, and the *Book of Circus*, you can see they have a connection that no one else has.

Throughout *Black Butler*, Ciel is always smiling when someone compliments Sebastian and Sebastian never turns down an order from Ciel nor does he hate it, he just finds it amusing. And on top of all of that, Ciel loves playing little games with Sebastian as well as does Sebastian love doing that to Ciel.

But some of y'all say that Sebastian is a demon. If he doesn't feel human emotions, then why does he love cats and shower them with affection? It tells me that yes, he is a demon and we saw in the *Book of Atlantic* how he really was, but then he changed. Also, the undertaker found it shocking and weird for a demon to be treating his master like how Sebastian treats Ciel. If you watch the *Book of Atlantic*, you would have seen the undertaker wanting to find out why Sebastian is so attached to Ciel and the grim reapers also found it weird too, and on *top of all that*, Claude, a season 2 demon also found it weird why he is risking his life for his food and why he is so attached.

We still didn't got an answer from Sebastian, then there's only Sebastian that can touch Ciel and calm him down. The *Book of Circus* will show you more about this. So Sebastian has some type of love for Ciel that we can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is coming from somebody who has only seen Black Butler animated and is completely ignorant of the manga, so this answer may not be completely accurate.

Does Sebastian care for Ciel? Well, he cares for Ciel's life, he cares for Ciel's resolve, and he cares for Ciel becoming a tasty meal for him. Does he see Ciel as a friend? Probably not.

In Book of the Atlantic, Madam Red tells Sebastian that he is practically like family to Ciel, in which Sebastian responds by saying "I would never presume to think of myself as family, that would be inappropriate. No, I am merely one hell of a butler." I assume that the same would go for friendship. This is further backed up in episode 15 of the first season, where Agni refers to Sebastian as a friend, and Sebastian is caught off guard, explaining that nobody had ever referred to him as such. I doubt that Sebastian sees any friendship between him and Ciel, at least nothing beyond master and servant or contractor and contractee.

You mentioned that Sebastian is always loyal to Ciel, and this is because it is a part of their contract. Sebastian is ordered to protect and never betray Ciel, along with never lying to him, and following his orders to their completion.

When Ciel and Sebastian's past together is revealed in Book of the Atlantic, you can see that Sebastian is initially very annoyed with Ciel, which makes sense considering that he is a demon having to play the role of a butler for a bratty little boy. But over time, I believe Sebastian grows to tolerate Ciel in the same way that Ciel tolerates him. They'd been together for three years and spent a lot of time training each other to be the perfect earl and butler. So while they may not be friends, they've been together long enough to not really mind each other.

I think it's also very important to note that while Sebastian only wants Ciel, Ciel needs Sebastian. I believe it is a lot more likely for Ciel to care for Sebastian than it is for Sebastian to care for Ciel considering that Sebastian has been Ciel's primary caretaker since his parents' death. However, while more likely, it isn't a very high chance that he actually does. Had Ciel actually gained those feelings towards Sebastian, I would imagine that Sebastian would have considered him too weak to complete his goal, and therefore eat his soul right then and there. I mean, what kind of earl would desire a friendship with a mere servant?

This is only my take on things, so it may not be entirely right. I believe the relationship between Ciel and Sebastian is very much up for personal interpretation, anyway!